# How can I list all sequences created by hibernate in mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have troubles with creating id field in hibernate. I want to list all sequences from mysql console. How?

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends a lot of how you've set up your sequences, but if you're using auto-increment `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`, the following SQL will give you a list of tables & columns which use auto_increment:

```
select * from information_schema.columns where extra like '%auto_increment%';
```

If you just want a list of tables, use

```
select * from information_schema.tables where auto_increment is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your package of Java entities (hibernate mappings), then do a search for the @ID annotation (assuming you are using annotations), and this will display your ID fields and the strategies employed to generate the ID (autogenerated, etc...).

For a comparison, you can also export the schema of your mysql database, and in a text editor, do a search for your auto_increment metadata.

But... what exactly is your problem with ID's ?